# Impact of copying a database in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I wish to make a local copy of a production SQL database hosted in Azure.

My understanding is that I do not have access to the built-in backups, and Export in the Azure Portal requires no write activity during export to be "transactionally consistent". So my best option is to make a copy of the database 
 in the Azure Portal and run Export from the copy.

Now for my question:
What is the impact of running the copy operation on my production database. I assume it does not lock it, but how will it affect performance during the copy?

I can not find any information regarding this in the Azure documentation.

Comment: You may have better luck here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you copy a normal database,it uses CPU,IO on the box it is in..

SQLAzure copy operations works the same way.I did a copy operation for a database and you can see data,cpu usage during the period(mine is s0)

further no operations were running on that database except copy and you can see once copy finishes DTU usage went to normal

**query used :**

```
select * from sys.resource_stats 
order by database_name,end_time desc
```

[image]